# Copy properties from one Javascript object to another object

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have 2 objects below:

```
const obj1 = {
    propertyA: 'a',
    propertyB: 'b',
    propertyC: 'c',
}

const obj2 = {
    propertyA:'aa',
    propertyB:'bb',
    ....  //so many properties includes all properties in obj1
    propertyZ:'zz',
}
```

I want each property in `obj1` has same value of property with the same name in `obj2`. Right now what I do is assign value of each property in `obj1` :

```
     obj1.propertyA = obj2.propertyA;
     obj1.propertyB = obj2.propertyB;
     obj1.propertyC = obj2.propertyC;
```

In my actual case `obj1` has lots more properties so this  is pretty annoying. And so I'm looking for a better way to optimize this, may be a function in Javascript or in some library like `Lodash` that I don't know. Anyone know how to solve this problem please share with me.

Comment: Just loop over the keys of obj1. `Object.keys(obj1).forEach(k => obj1[k] = obj2[k]);`

Answer (score 2):

You can simply loop over the [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) of obj1, check if obj2 has a matching property and if so assign its value to obj1. Here using a [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop.

```js
const obj1 = {
  propertyA: 'a',
  propertyB: 'b',
  propertyC: 'c',
}

const obj2 = {
  propertyA: 'aa',
  propertyB: 'bb',
  propertyZ: 'zz',
}

for (const k of Object.keys(obj1)) {
  if (k in obj2) {
    obj1[k] = obj2[k];
  }
}

console.log(obj1);
```

Comment: Is ther any advantage over `for (const k of Object.keys(obj1))` instead of `for (const k in obj1)`

Comment: `for...in` will traverse all enumerable properties including inherited properties often leading to the need to perform a `hasOwnProperty` check inside the loop. `Object.keys` only returns own properties of the objects, avoiding the need for the explicit check, but if inherited properties are desired in the loop then `for...in` is a fine choice.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to destructure your new object using the first one, thats it.

```
const obj1 = {
    propertyA: 'a',
    propertyB: 'b',
    propertyC: 'c',
}

const obj2 = {
    propertyA:'aa',
    propertyB:'bb',
    ...obj1,
    propertyZ:'zz',
}

console.log(obj2);
//you will get all the properties of obj1 into obj2
```

Comment: The OP wants to assign values to obj1 if obj2 has a matching property, not merge the objects